# Access Array from Property in Nested Object

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, nested, nested-object

I have the following nested object:

```
    export const mockData = {
    sections: [
        {
            name: 'Client',
            subSections: [
                {
                    name: 'Client Detail'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Sales',
            subSections: [
                {
                    name: 'Overview',
                    subSections: [
                        {
                            name: 'Overview - A',
                            fields: [
                                {
                                    key: 'firmName',
                                    type: 'input',
                                    templateOptions: {
                                        label: 'Firm Name',
                                        required: true
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    key: 'requestOption',
                                    type: 'select',
                                    templateOptions: {
                                        label: 'Request Option',
                                        required: true,
                                        options: [
                                            { value: '1', label: '1' },
                                            { value: '2', label: '2' },
                                            { value: '3', label: '3' },
                                            { value: '4', label: '4' }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    key: 'region',
                                    type: 'select',
                                    templateOptions: {
                                        label: 'Region',
                                        required: true,
                                        options: [
                                            { value: '1', label: '1' },
                                            { value: '2', label: '2' },
                                            { value: '3', label: '3' },
                                            { value: '4', label: '4' },
                                            { value: '5', label: '5' }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

and I would like to access the array from the `fields` property in order to render a form. Right now what I have is `overviewA: FormlyFieldConfig[] = mockData.sections[1].subSections[0].subSections[0].fields`, but I am facing the error of

```
Property 'subSections' does not exist on type '{ name: string; }'.
```

However, this error goes away when do a work-around and I add the property `subSections` to the nested object like so:

```
export const mockData = {
    sections: [
        {
            name: 'Client',
            subSections: [
                {
                    name: 'Client Detail',
                    subSections: []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Sales',
            subSections: [
                {
                    name: 'Overview',
                    subSections: [
                        {
                            name: 'Overview - A', ...
```

I was wondering why

1. I was facing the issue without the work-around, and
2. How can I access the array from the property `fields` without the work-around?

Comment: What does `FormlyFieldConfig` look like?

Comment: @Christian it is the field configurations for building a form using Angular's formly library, and it can be found [here](https://formly.dev/guide/properties-options)